Default window size for Jetpack Compose desktop
I'm writing an app in Jetpack Compose desktop, and I want it to open at a certain size. Similar to the --geometry argument for xterm.
Using the parameters to the Window() composable changes the size, but causes some flickering in Linux.
I haven't found anything that suggests that such a parameter exists, but I thought I would ask here before I go through the painful procedure of building the libraries myself from source.
Note that for Windows, it seems to work fine to use the Window() parameters, but in Linux, the window is initially created with the size 800x600 and then changed to whatever I specify in Window().
Alternatively - is there a way to force apps to open in a certain size in Xorg?

Not sure and haven't tried, but the most likely is changing the default value.
This is at least how eg. Nautilus does it. Just substitute org.gnome.nautilus:
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state initial-size '(1024,768)'

There's also other settings, eg. to start up with a maximized window.
If the values aren't picked up, you'll have to read the configuration.
Maybe check first with dconf, if the app even has an entry in there.

Thanks. This works for gnome, but not other window managers.

You didn't tell which window manager and GNOME is the most popular; and you probably won't get any better answer and I won't look it up for every single window manger out there, simply because this isn't my job. It's in every cause not the application itself defining the default size of a window.

Also on KDE with KWin, one can set KWin rules: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kwin/kcontrol/windowspecific/windowspecific.pdf
